# Searching for useful ternary codes

Tags: coding-theory

I'm trying to construct a $[108;60;16]_3$ code through concatenation, but I can't find a ternary code that'd help me with it. Hamming codes are binary, Golay's codes have distances of 5 and 6 which are not divisors of 16, the only Reed-Solomon code that is useful here is $[3;2;2]_3$, but it needs to use $[36;30;8]_9$ as an outer code which is even harder to construct. What ternary codes could be helpful here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $[27;20;8]_{27}$ (Reed-Solomon) and a single ternary parity check?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That's a fantastic suggestion, thanks! Would you mind formatting it as an answer so I can confirm it and close the question?

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered to some satisfaction in the comment by [Jyrki Lahtonen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11619/jyrki-lahtonen), as written by the poster in another comment.

From the comments:

"$[27;20;8]_{27}$ (Reed-Solomon) and a single ternary parity check?"

Answer (score 1):

Concatenation works like charm here.

Let us first describe a ternary code $\mathcal{C}_1$ with parameters $[4;3;2]_3$. That is easy, we simply extend any sequence $(t_1,t_2,t_3)$ of ternary symbols by adding a checksum
$$
t_4=t_1+t_2+t_3.
$$
The arithmetic is done modulo three (or in the prime field $\Bbb{F}_3$). The minimum Hamming distance is obviously $2$. For if $(t_1,t_2,t_3)$
and $(t_1',t_2',t_3')$ differ at only one position, then the corresponding checksums $t_4=t_1+t_2+t_3$ and $t_4'=t_1'+t_2'+t_3'$ are also different. So
the sequences $(t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4)$ and $(t_1',t_2',t_3',t_4')$ differ at at least
two positions. Let's denote this encoding process by
$$\psi:\Bbb{F}_3^3\to\Bbb{F}_3^4.$$

The other code we need is a Reed-Solomon code $\mathcal{C}_2$ with alphabet $\Bbb{F}_{27}$, length $n_2=27$, and rank $k_2=20$. Reed-Solomon codes are maximum distance separable (=they reach the Singleton bound), so this code has minimum distance $d_2=n_2-k_2+1=8$.

The way the concatenation works is that we fix some bijective linear mapping $\phi:\Bbb{F}_{27}\to\Bbb{F}_3^3$. Basically we fix a basis of $\Bbb{F}_{27}$ over the prime field, and use the coordinates w.r.t. that basis.

The desired concatenated code $\mathcal{C}$ can then be described as follows:

1. Take a sequence of sixty (information) symbols from $\Bbb{F}_3$.
2. Split that into twenty triples of symbols
   $s[k]:=(s_1[k],s_2[k],s_3[k])\in\Bbb{F}_3^3$, $k=1,2,\ldots,20$.
3. Use the inverse of $\phi$ to map these into a sequence of twenty symbols from the bigger field
   $$c[k]=\phi^{-1}(s[k])\in\Bbb{F}_{27}, k=1,2,\ldots,20.$$
4. Use the Reed-Solomon encoder to extend this sequence into a codeword
   $$c=(c[1],\cdots,c[20],c[21],\ldots,c[27])\in\Bbb{F}_{27}^{27}.$$
5. Apply the mapping $\phi$ to turn all these $27$ symbols from the bigger field into triples $\in\Bbb{F}_3^3$, and then extend all those triples into quartets by applying $\psi$ to arrive at the word
   $$
   x=(\psi(\phi(c[1])),\psi(\phi(c[2])),\ldots,\psi(\phi(c[27])))\in\Bbb{F}_3^{108}
   $$
   of the concatenated code $\mathcal{C}$.
   Each of the $27$ symbols from the bigger field were turned into quartets from the prime field, so in the end we have $4\cdot27=108$ ternary symbols altogether.

Everything in sight is linear, so this is a $[108,60]_3$-code. If $x$ is a non-zero codeword, then so is the vector $c$. Because the R-S code has minimum distance $8$, we can deduce that $c$ has at least eight non-zero components. Each and every one of those $\ge8$ were turned into a quartet (by applying $\psi$) with at least two non-zero components. Therefore $x$ has at least $2\cdot8=16$ non-zero symbols. As the code is linear, its minimum distance is thus $d_{min}(\mathcal{C})\ge 16.$

Comment: Hopefully it is now clear to all my critics, why it is not always so straightforward to promote a comment into an answer! I don't remember what distracted me from doing so at the time the question was asked. I don't think my comment would have served the Math.SE community very well in that brief form (even though the OP as a relative expert was satisfied).